# Puzzle: Calculate amount of combinations of "houses"

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I've found this enigma in a french book and I've tried using combinatorics to find the answer but I've been unsuccessful, could you help me out?

Here's what's given:
"A child wants to build "houses" using identical cubes. For him, making a house is just building the front wall, by juxtaposing "towers" of 1,2,3... floors, i.e. columns that are only limited in height by the number of cubes available.
Thus, with 3 cubes, he can build 4 different "houses".
And with 4 cubes? **Without building them all**, can you find out how many houses he can build with 10 cubes?"

Here's a link to the original problem with a helpful image so you can visualize the problem:
[The french puzzle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VD6Yu.png)

Comment: partitions where order matters. $2^9$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by sku already gives an answer: given $n$ cubes, each *house* corresponds to an ordered partitioning of $n$, ie $n_1+\cdots+n_k=n$ where the $n_i$ are ordered and positive. So $3$ can be partitioned in 4 different ways: $3$, $2+1$, $1+2$, and $1+1+1$.

There are several ways to derive the number of ordered partitions for general $n$. However, here's a particularly simple one which nicely translates to building the house.

Start by placing a single cube. For each subsequent cube, either stack it on top of the last one building the tower taller, or place it to the left starting a new tower. Ie, for each cube except the first, you have two choices. Every house can be built in this way, and every sequence of choices gives rise to a different house.

Hence, there are $2^{n-1}$ different houses that can be built from $n$ cubes.

---

*Actually, the above was not my original way to solve this. To intrigue those not familiar with generating functions, here is my initial approach:*

A house consists of a sequence of towers, each tower consisting of 1 or more cubes. The number of towers with $n\ge1$ cubes is 1, and we can represent this by a power series:
$$
T(x)
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty
  \#(\text{towers with $n$ cubes})\cdot x^n
= x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots = \frac{x}{1-x}.
$$
Note that for $n=0$, the coefficient will be zero.

If we do the same with $k$ towers, we get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty
 \#(\text{$k$ tower houses with $n$ cubes in total})
 \cdot x^n
= T(x)^k
$$
and we sum this for $k=1,2,\ldots$ towers to count all possible houses, we get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty
 \#(\text{houses with $n$ cubes})
 \cdot x^n
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty T(x)^k
= \frac{T(x)}{1-T(x)}
= \frac{x}{1-2x}
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{n-1}x^n
$$
from which we can read the number of houses with $n$ cubes as $2^{n-1}$. Seeing this, I realised there had to be a simpler proof.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed! :)